# Max reps, boredom and carpet-burn

Tags: training, squats, push-ups, reps, sit-ups

Is there any consensus on the maximum number of reps you should perform, before rotating?

Curious as I find I get bored, or start to get say carpet burn (sit-ups), if the number exceeds a hundred. Personally I choose not to do more than 60 of anything, also find 60 a useful number for timing. Then again, back in my student days, I've had house mates who'd happily do 500 push-ups, immediately rotate into 1,000 sit-ups, then on to many squats, as a warm up, before throwing up last night bottle of Vodka over the nearest parked car (learnt were not to park), so I guess it's entirely personal/subjective, but is there any general advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is generally no consensus about anything. We all have different bodies. We all react differently to different stimuli.

That said, 60 reps of anything is a stamina exercise, and not a strength exercise. And your friends who did hundreds, weren't developing strength. They were developing further the ability to do hundreds of reps.

The best advice we generally give, is if you can do more than 20 reps per set, add weight, such that you can do 8-12 reps per set instead.

See other related questions/answers:

[How many sets and reps should I do as a beginner?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9833/how-many-sets-and-reps-should-i-do-as-a-beginner?rq=1)

[Are 15 reps too many for increasing muscular endurance?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/9773/are-15-reps-too-many-for-increasing-muscular-endurance?lq=1)

[Is doing the whole rep range from 3 to 15 reps before adding weight a waste of time?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/24767/is-doing-the-whole-rep-range-from-3-to-15-reps-before-adding-weight-a-waste-of-t?rq=1)

As for alcohol and working out, I think the answer is pretty self-explanatory. If your liver is hard at work with filtering alcohol out of your system, how is it supposed to handle protein for your muscles?