# Effects of doing many push ups, pull ups, dips?

Tags: push-ups, pull-ups, muscle-gain, calisthenics, dips

I am wondering if doing lots of push ups(100), lots of pull ups(50), and lots of dips(40) daily will build muscles. That's all. Thanks.

Comment: 40 is relatively few dips compared to 50 pullups.

Comment: related: [Max reps, boredom and carpet-burn](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25749/max-reps-boredom-and-carpet-burn)

Answer (score 4):

It will, up to a point. If you can only do 5-10 straight reps before having to break then it's still heavy enough to build decent muscle for you. Once you can do around fifteen or more in a row, however, it'll start to become decreasingly effective.

Answer (score 2):

The body responds to shock. Once you can successfully do 100 pushups, 50 pullups and 40 dips daily the body will no longer consider this a shock and rather a routine. At this point, if you keep at it, you will notice a decrease in muscle mass, but not a decrease in strength. Your body was piling up all those muscles because you told it to. Now its realising that it doesn't need all those muscles and can do the job with half less. The extra muscles are just extra maintenance so it will get rid of them.

To answer your question: Yes it will build strength, but after a while you might want to change it up for something new.

Comment: ***Are you mixing strength with endurance?*** 100 pushups won't build strength; it'll build endurance.

Comment: 50 muscle ups is no easy thing. You do need strength to achieve this. But once you do its best to move forward with either a different exercise or a weighted variation.

Comment: I guarantee you that if you successfully do 100 pushups, 50 pullups and 40 dips every day you will **not** notice a decrease in muscle mass, unless 1) you stop taking anabolic steroids or 2) you're very, very big and at the same time stop doing any other heavy weight lifting you may have been doing.