# 60 push ups at once? or 4 series of 15?

Tags: push-ups

I'm doing 60 push ups mon - wed - fri.
I'm making the 60 moves in 4 series with a break of 30 seconds per series.

What's best, doing 60 push ups at once or 4 series of 15?

Comment: related: [Max reps, boredom and carpet-burn](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/25749/max-reps-boredom-and-carpet-burn)

Comment: What are your goals for doing push ups? Without taking goals into consideration, too many answers can be given.

Comment: my goal is to increase my triceps as fast as I can

Comment: Why not do both?

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to increase triceps as you mentioned in your comment, doing regular pushups will not be enough, especially not if you can make 60.

According to current science, the ideal way to grow most muscles is to to exercises heavy enough that you can only do 10 of them in a set, 5-15 works, but around 10 seems to be ideal, if you can do more than 15 in a set, you're only increasing stamina.

So either change to another exercise, or modify your pushups. Put on a backpack or something else that's heavy on your back, or google other variants of pushups that are harder.